# ngFor not updating when pushing new data

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-reactive-forms

I have a set of reactive forms that I'm setting up as an array of reactive forms:

```
typesForms: FormGroup[] = [];
```

Which I loop through in my html:

```
<form *ngFor="let type of typesForms; let i = index" [formGroup]="typesForms[i]" class="row">
```

However, when I push a new form, the HTML doesn't update.

```
this.typesForms.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    type: { value: data['type'], disabled: true }
}));
```

I've logged out the resulting data, and it shows the new form object, but nothing on the front end. I assume this has something to do with reactive forms, but I'm not sure if I'm screwing something else up.

Comment: Your ngFor iterates on types, not on typesForms. So adding an element to typesForms won't change anything.

Comment: Oops, that's just a typo. I was testing out some stuff and accidentally copied my test code. Fixing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just `<form *ngFor="let type of typesForm" [formGroup]="type" class="row">`?

---

Update:

If you have multiple forms you can utilize Angular's built-in [FormArray](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html) data structure. It does simplifying manipulations on set of form groups - allows you to easily track changes and validate linked `FormGroup`'s or `FormControl`'s.

[**Punkr example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/IGEwXMcVJbf0xRJWK8lj?p=preview)

Note: thanks to how things structured under the `ReactiveFormsModule` *hood* you can compose `FormArray`s, `FormGroup`s and `FormControl`s as you want:

- you can have a `FormArray` as field a of `FormGroup`
- `FormArray` can contain `FormArray`s, `FormGroup`s and `FormControl`s

Comment: I didn't, as I need the index for interacting with the form, unless there's another way to do it that I don't know of. I'll try to see if that helps, though I'll need to look up how else to interact with the individual forms.

Comment: I've made an example in this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GPRvGZrLQYWdJ9zVouQy) that shows how you can instantiate and control multiple form groups with [Form Array](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html)